# Populate vs $in efficiency in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I am querying for user-connections of a User. I would like to also show the most current tagline of the user-connections of that User.

As the tagline is in the User-model and not in the user-connections, I need to fetch it alongside getting the user-connections.

Right now I do that with $in, is populate a better option? Is there a better way to do this? As taglines may be updated by users, I do not want to store them in the userconnections, otherwise I have to always update each userconnection if a tagline changes.

My User-connnection model:

```
var UserConnectionsSchema   = new Schema({

    userID: {type: String, index: true},
    userName: String,  
    userTargetID: String,
    userTargetName: String,
    connectionStatus: String,
});
```

An extract from my user model

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({

    name: String,
    email: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    password: { type: String, select: false },

    tagline: String,

});
```

And here is how I currently get the taglines with $in:

```
apiRouter.route('/users')

        .get(function(req, res) {

            UserConnection.find( { $and : [ { userID : req.decoded.id }, 
                { connectionStatus : 'accepted' } ] }).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(30).exec(function(err, connections) {
                if (err) res.send(err); 

                //we also find the taglines for the users
                if (!err) {
                    searchArray = [];
                    for (i=0; i < connections.length; i++) {
                        searchArray.push(connections[i].userTargetID);
                    }
                    console.log(searchArray);

                    User.find({'_id': { $in: searchArray }}).select("tagline").exec(function(err2, users){                      
                        if (err2) res.send(err2);
                        console.log(users);
                        if (!err2) {    
                            res.json({"connections": connections, "users": users});
                        }
                    });

                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use `populate` as you have no reference field to the `UserSchema` in your `UserConnectionsSchema`.

Comment: Hi Mikey, I can change the UserTargetID to a reference instead of a string. What I am wondering is if this is a better practice than just fetching the records, extracting the IDs (currently strings) and getting the taglines then. It might be irrelevant optimization, but I am curious what is the better practice and more efficient.